# How to format SQL query output properly in Tkinter?

Tags: python, sql-server, tkinter

I am having trouble outputting my SQL queries properly.  I have posted this earlier but I don't think I explained it very well.  I am using an entry widget for at least 10 rows in a SQL query.

The program can search for a first name or last name and provide a list of names tied to the search criteria.
It should only list the name in relation to the present query.

Right now, if you enter a name, it will list all the people that have the same name.  Then if you do a second search, it will list the new name plus the previous names you searched for.  I am trying to figure out how to properly clear it so that the previous names will no longer show.

I am attaching a screen shot of 3 searches from a database of random names.

The first search is for the first name Burney.  There is only one Burney in my database so it lists that one Burney.
Second, Josh is searched for.  There are probably around 20 Josh's in the datbase so it overwrites Burney and lists Josh names.
Third, Burney is search for again.
Well, it only overwrites the top Entry row with Burney but leaves all of the previous Josh names.
I only want it to show Burney.

I have played with self.myentry.delete(0, END) in the results[x] but I am not sure if I am using it properly. Or if it would even help my situation.

Attached is a screenshot and a short version of my code:

[image]

```
import os
import pypyodbc
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import BOTH, END, LEFT


class Adder(ttk.Frame):
    """The adders gui and functions."""
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = parent
        self.init_gui()

    def calculate(self):
        firstname = str(self.first_entry.get())
        lastname = str(self.last_entry.get())     

        if (firstname and not lastname):  # "You entered first name."

            try:
                connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=MYSERVERNAME;Database=MYDATABASE;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
            except pypyodbc.Error as ex:
                sqlstate = ex.args[0]
                if sqlstate == '28000':
                    self.answer_label['text'] = "You do not have access." 
            cursor = connection.cursor() 
            SQLCommand = ("SELECT LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME "      
                "FROM dbo.MYTABLENAMEHERE "   # table name
                "with (nolock)"
                "WHERE FIRSTNAME = ?")
            Values = [firstname]
            cursor.execute(SQLCommand,Values)
            results = cursor.fetchmany(10)
            if results:
                self.output0.delete(0, END)
                self.output0.insert(0,results[0])
                self.output1.insert(0,results[1])
                self.output2.insert(0,results[2])
                self.output3.insert(0,results[3])
                self.output4.insert(0,results[4])
                connection.close()


    def init_gui(self):
        """Builds GUI."""
        self.root.title('Verify')
        self.root.option_add('*tearOff', 'FALSE')

        self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew') # this starts the entire form

        # Input Boxes and Button

        self.first_entry = tkinter.Entry(self, width=28) # first input box
        self.first_entry.grid(sticky='', column=1, row=1) 

        self.last_entry = tkinter.Entry(self, width=28) # second input box
        self.last_entry.grid(sticky='', column=2, row=1) 


        self.calc_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Search', command=self.calculate) # button
        self.calc_button.grid(column=4, row=1, columnspan=1, sticky='w', padx=14)

        # Output entries for answers

        self.output0 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, bd=0,)
        self.output0.grid(column=0, row=6, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)
        self.output1 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, bd=0,)
        self.output1.grid(column=0, row=7, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)
        self.output2 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, bd=0,)
        self.output2.grid(column=0, row=8, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)
        self.output3 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, bd=0,)
        self.output3.grid(column=0, row=9, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)
        self.output4 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, bd=0,)
        self.output4.grid(column=0, row=10, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    Adder(root)
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False) # locks window from being resized
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you sure you are deleting contents of the right Entry? On your second calculate, Burney might just go out of screen because of number of Joshes. In your code it seems like you have five Entry widgets for output but only deleting contents of one them. So you _might_ be deleting contents of wrong one and only keep inserting new results to other Entry.

Comment: Why not use a `Text` widget to display the results rather than 5 separate `Entry` widgets

Comment: I have tried using self.output0.delete(0, END) for each different output entry and it doesn't seem to make any difference except that it deletes the second row on future queries.                I was wondering if there was a way I could write something like:  check results 0-9, if results is empty, delete that row and all other after in the Entry widgets.